# Creating a 3 way table using R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a 3 way table using R.

I have used the below code in summarizing the data and coming up with a 3 way table

```
3waydata <- data %>% group_by(duration, education, sex) %>%
                     summarise(count = sum(number))
```

And then come up with the following table

```
with(3waydata, table(duration, sex, education)
```

However I'm not sure how to include the counts within the table. I have the structure I want but am unsure how to include the counts within the table.

```
                           education high low medium unknown
duration             sex                                   
five-to-ten-years   female            1   1      1       1
                    male              1   1      1       1
five-years-or-less  female            1   1      1       1
                    male              1   1      1       1
more-than-ten-years female            1   1      1       1
                    male              1   1      1       1
native-born         female            1   1      1       1
                    male              1   1      1       1
unknown             female            1   1      1       1
                    male              1   1      1       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the table you want, you can use `xtabs` and `ftable`:

```
with(`3waydata`, ftable(xtabs(count ~ duration + sex + education)))
#>                         education high low medium unknown
#> duration            sex                                  
#> five-to-ten-years   F                8   0     10       0
#>                     M                0   9     12      11
#> five-years-or-less  F               10  10      0       9
#>                     M                9  14     15      12
#> more-than-ten-years F               22  26     29      10
#>                     M                0  12     31       0
#> native-born         F                0   0     11       0
#>                     M               12   0      0       0
#> unknown             F                0  13      0       0
#>                     M                0  12     15      11
```

---

Obviously, I had to create my own data since you did not supply your own. Please note that `3waydata` is not a valid variable name in R, so has no be wrapped in quotes.

```
set.seed(69)

data <- data.frame(education = sample(c("high","low","medium","unknown"), 30, T),
                   sex       = rep(c("M", "F"), 15),
                   duration  = sample(c("unknown", "native-born", 
                                        "five-years-or-less", "five-to-ten-years",
                                        "more-than-ten-years"), 30, T),
                   number    = rpois(30, 10))

`3waydata` <- data %>% 
              group_by(duration, education, sex) %>%
              summarise(count = sum(number))
```